# MySQL not working after updating to Windows 8.1

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Everything was working fine, I had Windows 8 and MySQL 5.6 workbench.

Yesterday, I upgraded to Windows 8.1 which made the PC run better but messed up the MySQL.

When I enter the workbench I can see my old connection but by clicking on it I get:

```
Cannot Connect to Database Server
Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 
127.0.0.1:3306:Can't connect to mysql server on '127.0.0.1'(10061)
Please:
 1. Check that mysql is running on server 127.0.0.1
 2. Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
 3. Check the root has rights to connect to 127.0.0.1 from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines) 
 4. Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for 127.0.0.1 connecting from the host address you're connecting from the host address you're connecting from.
```

Comment: did you check your firewall settings?

Comment: Is the MySQL service started successfully ? Is your MySQL listening to port 3306 ?

Comment: now, i took the firewall down and it works now, but all my SCHEMAS are missing (OMG!!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, Uninstalling workbench and re-installing it did the trick.
All Schemas were not deleted

Comment: I had the same exact problem. I uninstalled and re-installed, however, I still cannot connect.

On the dashboard I can click into the Local instance, then it brings me to an "Administration" page, but it says in like 3 different places "Server Status: Unknown". 

Any tips you can give?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I had to reinstall the service too http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html

Thanks again!

Comment: That didn't work for me Richard. I had to reinstall MySQL Server to get it to work again. The schemas were not removed.

Comment: Confirmed. This worked for me as well. Uninstalled Workbench & SQL Server, then re installed. Schemas was reloaded. Windows 8.1 Update is a pain!

Comment: The workbench doesn't have anything to do with that, it's just actually the server which isn't running. If you expect a service, check if it's there (mine wasn't) and reinstall it if necessary, according to the (MySQL) documentation mentioned above.

Comment: Uninstall then subsequent Reinstall of Mysql entirely worked here. what gives Microsoft? Is it any wonder the world hates you.

Comment: A couple answers below talk about reinstalling the service. That route worked for me without uninstalling/reinstalling the whole thing. Thanks for the pain, microsoft.

Comment: Can you really blame microsoft for this?!? Are people thinking logically?

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling the mysqld service will indeed get the database server to start up again, but you will find that your databases are missing, as are all your user details!

Under Windows 8, MySQL stores its databases under C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data while under 8.1 it has all moved to C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data.

The quick solution to this is:

- Stop the mysqld service via MySQL Notifier in the task bar
- Copy C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5 to C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5
- Restart the mysqld service via the Notifier.

Hey presto, your databases and user credentials are back.

Answer (score 2):

After upgrade to Windows 8.1 you either need to run the MySQL config wizard

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-starting.html

But I could not get that to work, so had to reinstall the MySQL Server.

Then to install it as a service, and point to my earlier databases:

```
mysqld --install MySQL --defaults-file=C:\MySQL\data\my.ini
```

Check it's working by running

```
mysql -u username -p password
show databases;
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the service of mysql was missing. Reinstalling the service with the following command:

```
mysqld --install [Instance Name] --defaults-file=[My SQL Configuration File]
```

so, if my install the service, with `MySQL` is the instance name, and `D:\MySQL\my.ini` was my previous configuration file, I executed the following command:

```
mysqld --install MySQL --defaults-file="D:\MySQL\my.ini"
```

Then start the service as usual. That should do the trick.

Note: You have to execute those command in a command prompt with elevated privilege.