# Mysql Configuration instance error

Tags: mysql, windows-8.1

[image]

Am using windows 8 and mysql 5.5 am unable to install as the system is halting at the above stage. Previously mysql was working fine, but some download of the driver had corrupted it. so uninstalled it and am trying to reinstall. Kindly suggest how to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL not working after updating to Windows 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514279/mysql-not-working-after-updating-to-windows-8-1)

Comment: share errors from log file...if u are able to check.

Comment: where can i find them..